# if condition is not executing if using the below logic

Tags: java

```
how to display executed    
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));  
System.out.println("enter number");  
String number = br.readLine();  
System.out.println("enter name");  
string name = br.readLine();  
if(!number.equals(" ")  && name.equals(" "))  
System.out.println("executed");
```

in the above code if i give value 1 to number and for name if i don't give any value( i.e simply pressing enter) then the if condition should be executed but its not working????

Comment: If you just press enter, won't `name` be `""` rather than `" "`?

Comment: try `name.trim().isEmpty()`

Comment: `java.util.Scanner` is your friend

Answer (score 2):

> for name if i don't give any value( i.e simply pressing enter)

That does not leave `name` with the value of a string with a single space - i.e. the one that your `if` is looking for. Print the values that you get back to see what you are getting, then modify the condition accordingly:

```
System.out.println("number=|"+ number + "|, name=|" + name + "|");
```

The above adds delimiters to the strings so that you could easily determine the length of their content.

Answer (score 1):

You have string name but it needs to be String name and you can check if an string is empty by doing `if(number.length() != 0 && name.length() != 0) {}`